# Regular expression to match CSS rules

Tags: html, css, regex, expression, preg-match

Example original CSS:

```
.sk-hybrid{}
.sk-hybrid header > .row,
.sk-hybrid > #content.row,
.sk-hybrid footer > .row{}
.sk-border-radius-sm{}
.sk-gradient-gray-sm{}
```

I want to preg_replace all instances of **.sk-whatever{** to **.sk-whatever-i{** and all instances of the same terms followed by a space, like **.sk-whatever ** to **.sk-whatever-i **

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is, write some PHP code that will parse my CSS file to add the "-i" to all instances of my **.sk-someword** class. So I can then append the !important declaration to the ruleset but that's easy enough.

I need the regX only to add the "-i". Please note that .sk-whatever might have special characters between.

```
.sk-some-class-term(space)
```

or

```
.sk-some-class-term{
```

I'm such a slob when it comes to regX. I'm pretty sure others can write this easily. I can't. Help please? :(

The result of my example CSS should be:

```
.sk-hybrid-i{}
.sk-hybrid-i header > .row,
.sk-hybrid-i > #content.row,
.sk-hybrid-i footer > .row{}
.sk-border-radius-sm-i{}
.sk-gradient-gray-sm-i{}
```

Comment: `!important` is heavily discouraged in CSS. What exactly are you wanting to achieve as your end result?

Comment: I intend to make it so that, when you add a class .sk-border-radius to an element, it will save me from typing all the webkit stuff. It's tedious. But sometimes the specificity of the CSS inheritance will prevent me from doing so. That's where I use .sk-border-radius-i instead because I know this is a version of my class that has the !important declaration. However, I am not going to rewrite my (often updated, mind you) common stylesheet by hand. Hence the PHP parsing.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work for your purposes:

```
^(\.sk-\w+(?:[^\{\s,>]+))
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU9rU7/3)

**Explanation**

- `^` Matches beginning of string
- `(` Begin capture group

  - `\.sk-\w+` Matches `.sk-` followed by letters or numbers
  - `(?:` Begin non-capturing group

    - `[^\{\s,>]+` Matches any non-whitespace, non-`{`, non-`,`, or non-`>` character
  - `)` End non-capturing group
- `)` End capture group

Answer (score 1):

Match

```
(\.sk(-\w+)+)
```

and replace with `$1-i`: http://regex101.com/r/nC8kU1/1

However, much better would be to use a dedicated tool, that, unlike regexes, "understands" the underlying language. For php, there's https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser, pay attention to the [Prepend id to selectors](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser#use-parser-to-prepend-an-id-to-all-selectors) example - it's almost what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmmm, your solution is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

PHP to do what you are asking where `$cssString` is set to your css.

```
$cssString = preg_replace ( '(\.sk-\w+(?:[^\{\s,>]+))',  '$1-i', $cssString);
```

Though if you are running on linux, just use sed

```
sed 's/^(\.sk-\w+(?:[^\{\s,>]+))/$0-i/g' example.css
```

Comment: Had to go with '$0-i' instead to make it work. I don't know how it did I just read it from another thread, but the preg_replace code worked nicely. Cheers mate!

Comment: Updated the code, seems strange to me that it's $0 but if it works that's good :)